# Node.js This Fiber is already running

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-fibers

I have a question regarding usage of Fibers in Node.js. The following code fails with error message:

> This Fiber is already running

on `train` routine.

```
var f = Fiber(function() {
  var fiber = Fiber.current;

  utils.enseeds(seeds, function(err, response){
    fiber.run(response)
  })

  var myseeds = Fiber.yield()

  utils.train(train, test, myseeds, function(err, response){
    fiber.run(response)
  })

  var stats = Fiber.yield()
})

f.run();
```

For some reason it doesn't like `myseeds`, if I change `myseeds` in `train` to something else it works. Why does this happen?